# Are gluten free diets in violation of the word of wisdom?

Tags: lds, christian-living, doctrine-and-covenants, diet, word-of-wisdom

Aside from celiacs and others with medical disorders which prevent them from eating certain grains, is there an official LDS church stance in relation to people who optionally choose to live a gluten free lifestyle, based on these verses in the word of wisdom:

> 14 **All grain is ordained for the use of man and of beasts, *to be the staff of life***, [...]
>
> 16 **All grain is good for the food of man**; as also the fruit of the vine; that which yieldeth fruit, whether in the ground or above the ground—
>
> 17 **Nevertheless, wheat for man**, and corn for the ox, and oats for the horse, and rye for the fowls and for swine, and for all beasts of the field, and barley for all useful animals, and for mild drinks, as also other grain. ([D&C 89:14,16-17](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/89.14,16-17?lang=eng#13))

Comment: Please no arguing in comments.  It looked like @Flimzy was asking a question: " Is this distinction meaningful to the question? ", which is allowed under the guidelines for using comments - They can be used to request clarification on a post. it looks like ShemSheger mistook his purpose, but all in all, the comments quickly took a turn to look like bickering, so I'm deleting them.

Comment: I would simply encourage you to research what gluten actually is, and why you think you want to be free of it. It's actually quite healthy and nutritious if you are not allergic to it. I would have no issue with it any more than a vegan or vegetarian diet, it is purely by choice. But by this reasoning we should not eat corn either, because it's only for ox?

Comment: @joshuabigbee I know perfectly well what gluten is, and consume mass portions of the foods stuffs made from gluten rich grass fruits. I'm not gluten free, I'm the guy who is critical of gluten free diets.

Comment: Well first of all, that isn't clear in the question.  Not that it should be,  but there is no need to respond as though I should have known it. Secondly,  I would simply amend my comment to be "to anyone considering it" instead of specifically "you". There is just a lot of ignorance on this and other dietary topics and I simply wished to encourage anyone reading this to make themselves educated.

Comment: @JoshuaBigbee I totally agree there is a lot of ignorance, my comment wasn't meant to be confrontational, it just hadn't occurred to me that I may be mistaken as one of those gluten free bandwagon riders, and I wanted it to be clear to everyone that I was not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe. Remember that the D&C 89 was prefaced with:

> To be sent greeting; not by commandment or constraint, but by revelation and the word of wisdom, showing forth the order and will of God in the temporal salvation of all saints in the last days—
>
> Given for a principle with promise, adapted to the capacity of the weak and the weakest of all saints, who are or can be called saints.
>
> D&C 89:2

In since the late 1800s, the principles contained in D&C 89 have been codified by various statements of prophets. Some have clarified it, for example hot drinks being tea and coffee, and others have added to it Word of Wisdom, for example illegal drugs.

While D&C 89 is referenced during any discussion of the commandments of health, they are not exactly the same.

Wheat consumption is not a strict part of the Lord's law of health; i.e., one that precludes good standing in the Church. Perhaps a gluten-free diet is a "minor" sin; we can't really say. Many commandments are intentionally left to personal revelation.

> And finally, I cannot tell you all the things whereby ye may commit sin; for there are divers ways and means, even so many that I cannot number them.
>
> Mosiah 4:29

John Taylor quoted Joseph Smith as describing his method of governance:

> I teach them correct principles, and they govern themselves.

In summary, D&C 89 suggests eating wheat; the Word of Wisdom does not require it.

---

FYI, in additional to celiac disease, there is [non-celiac gluten sensitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-celiac_gluten_sensitivity). It can happen at any severity, and diagnosis is really only possible after comparing gluten and non-gluten diets. Individual circumstance make a difference.

> And see that all these things are done in wisdom and order; for it is not requisite that a man should run faster than he has strength.
>
> Mosiah 4:27

Answer (score 4):

There is no doctrinal condemnation for gluten free diets.  The Lord expects us to make judgement calls based on what we are given in many instances.  Someone living glueten free will not be kept from the temple.

In [Doctrine and Covenants 58, verse 26](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/58.26?lang=eng) the Lord said:

> For behold, it is not meet that I should command in all things; for he that is compelled in all things, the same is a slothful and not a wise servant; wherefore he receiveth no reward.

A lot of things are not black and white.

In [Preach My Gospel, Chapter 4](https://www.lds.org/manual/preach-my-gospel-a-guide-to-missionary-service/lesson-4-the-commandments?lang=eng), the missionary handbook, this is the "black and white" of the Word of Wisdom

> Remember that our bodies are sacred. We should treat them with respect and reverence. The Word of Wisdom teaches that we are to eat healthy foods. It teaches very specifically that we are to avoid harmful substances, including alcohol, tobacco, tea, and coffee. We must also avoid harmful drugs in any form.

I believe the answer to this question is personal and between the individual and God.